# Next.js: pass additional props to the page during static export?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to statically export a next.js app. The [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export) says the page object has only 2 values: `page` and `query`. Is there a way to pass additional props to the page?

I've tried to use `query` for this, but it seems that next's router is not aware of the route's `query` object. Hence it didn't work.

In other words, I have a list of blog posts at build time, how could I inline them to the page (page component)?

I guess `react-static` has a `routeInfo.json` which is prefetched for every route. I wonder if there is anything similar to it in next.js.

Comment: this thread https://spectrum.chat/next-js/general/access-static-export-props-on-client~6a49106f-7ca5-4d82-afcb-dc48bdc2c42b

Comment: the feature request https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/4810

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPD Apr 4 20**
At least in the [next.js 9.3](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-9-3#next-gen-static-site-generation-ssg-support) there are `getStaticProps` and `getStaticPaths`

[(complete example)](https://github.com/evgeny-t/test-get-static-props/blob/master/pages/index.tsx)

```
const IndexPage: NextPage<{ names: string[] }> = (props) => {
  return (
    <main>
      <section>
        {props.names.map((name) => (
          <div key={name}>
            <Link href={`/users/${name}`}>
              <a>{name}</a>
            </Link>
          </div>
        ))}
      </section>
    </main>
  );
};

export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async () => {
  const data: User[] = readJsonSync("./data.json");

  return {
    props: {
      names: data.map((user) => user.name),
    },
  };
};

export default IndexPage;
```

**UPD Dec 4 19**

There is an RFC for `getStaticProps` which solves this: https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/9524

---

Here is what I ended up with.

_app.js:

```
import React from "react";
import App, { Container } from "next/app";

import fs from "fs";
import { resolve, join } from "path";

export default class extends App {
  static async getInitialProps({ Component, ctx }) {
    const { req, asPath } = ctx;
    let pageProps = {};

    if (Component.getInitialProps) {
      pageProps = await Component.getInitialProps(ctx);
    }

    let p;
    if (req) {
      p = JSON.parse(
        fs.readFileSync(resolve(join("data", asPath, "route.json"))).toString()
      );
    } else {
      p = await (await fetch(`/data${asPath}/route.json`)).json();
    }

    return { pageProps: { ...pageProps, ...p } };
  }

  render() {
    const { Component, pageProps } = this.props;
    return (
      <Container>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

in next.config.js:

```
const fetch = require("isomorphic-unfetch");
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
const fse = require("fs-extra");
const withBundleAnalyzer = require("@next/bundle-analyzer")({
  enabled: false
});

module.exports = withBundleAnalyzer({
  webpack(config) {
    config.node = { fs: "empty", path: "empty" };
    return config;
  },
  async exportPathMap() {
    const response = await fetch(
      "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?_page=1"
    );
    const postList = await response.json();
    fs.writeFileSync(
      path.resolve(`data/route.json`),
      JSON.stringify({ postList }, null, 2)
    );
    for (let i = 0; i < postList.length; ++i) {
      const id = postList[i].id;
      const response = await fetch(
        `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${id}`
      );
      const post = await response.json();
      const fn = path.resolve(`data/post/${id}/route.json`);

      await fse.outputFile(fn, JSON.stringify(post, null, 2));
    }

    const pages = postList.reduce(
      (pages, post) =>
        Object.assign({}, pages, {
          [`/post/${post.id}`]: {
            page: "/post"
          }
        }),
      {}
    );

    return Object.assign({}, pages, {
      "/": { page: "/" }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: This is awesome, thank you for sharing. I wanted a solution that only requested global data once during compile and never during client side routes. I used your file write from the `exportPathMap` callback to cache a request once during export and accessed the data client side using the `__NEXT_DATA__` window global. 

See conversation here: https://spectrum.chat/next-js/general/fetching-global-site-data-once-and-reusing-in-multiple-pages~0eb49896-407a-4405-8ca7-091907a65ac8?m=MTU3MzIzNjc3ODM0NA==